# What blocks exist in Minecraft BE that do NOT exist in JE and vice-versa?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition, version-differences

I recently learned that there are blocks that exist within [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) that do NOT exist in [minecraft-java-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition). As a result, I'm left to wonder:

- What blocks exist in [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) that do NOT exist in [minecraft-java-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition)?
- What blocks exist in [minecraft-java-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition) that do NOT exist in [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Block#List_of_blocks), there are 12 blocks exclusive to [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) and 2 exclusive to [minecraft-java-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition):

| Block | Version |
| --- | --- |
| [Nether Reactor Core‌](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_Reactor_Core) | [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) |
| [Stonecutter (legacy)‌](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Stonecutter_(old)) | [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) |
| [Glow Item Frame (As a block)](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Item_Frame) | [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) |
| [Glowing Obsidian](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Glowing_Obsidian) | [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) |
| [Item Frame (as a block)](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Item_Frame) | [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) |
| [Chiseled Purpur](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Purpur_Block) | [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) |
| [reserved6‌](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Reserved6) | [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) |
| [info_update](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Info_update) | [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) |
| [info_update2](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Info_update) | [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) |
| [Invisible Bedrock](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Invisible_Bedrock) | [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) |
| [Smooth Purpur](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Purpur_Block) | [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) |
| [Smooth Stone Bricks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Stone_Bricks) | [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) |
| - | - |
| [Cave Air](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Air) | [minecraft-java-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition) |
| [Void Air‌](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Air) | [minecraft-java-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition) |

However, through the education edition features available in [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition), an additional 49 blocks become available that are unavailable in [minecraft-java-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition). These are:

- [Allow and Deny](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Allow_and_Deny)
- [Border](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Border)
- [Board, Poster, and Slate](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chalkboard)
- [Colored Torch](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Colored_Torch)

  - Available in 4 colors: Blue, Green, Purple, Red
- [Compound Creator](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Compound_Creator)
- [Element Constructor](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Element_Constructor)
- [Heat Block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Heat_Block)
- [Lab Table](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lab_Table)
- [Material Reducer](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Material_Reducer)
- [Underwater TNT](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Underwater_TNT)
- [Underwater Torch](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Underwater_Torch)
- [Hardened Stained Glass and Pane](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Hardened_Glass)

  - Available in 17 colors: Black, Blue, Brown, Clear, Cyan, Gray, Green, Light Blue, Light Gray, Lime, Magenta, Orange, Pink, Purple, Red, White, Yellow

<sub>***Note**: The information in the table above is accurate as of August 2<sup>nd</sup>, 2021.*</sub>